# iOS CoreBluetooth reconnecting while app in background

Tags: ios, background, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

My question is "how do I go about reconnecting to a ble device once the app is not in the foreground"? I've done my research and it seems that the best way to connect to a paired ble device is through retrivePeripherals:UUID. Once it finds something the didRetivePeripherials is called back and here I can try to reconnect to the device again. I can't seem to be able to do this while the app is running on the background.

Help is appreciated.

Andresn N.

Answer (score 1):

1. Enable the `bluetooth-central` background mode
2. Use the `CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey` option supplying a unique identifier when instantiating your `CBCentralManager`
3. Implement the `- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central willRestoreState:(NSDictionary *)state` delegate method
   3.1 Get an array of restorable peripherals using `NSArray *peripherals = state[CBCentralManagerRestoredStatePeripheralsKey]`
   3.2 Call the `connectPeripheral` method of your `CBCentralManager` supplying each peripheral to restore

Read more of the details in the [Core Bluetooth Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html)

Comment: Wont connect if app is forced closed by user.